# Prove or disprove this table is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Any help will be appreciated on how to approach this and get started.

Comment: Hint:  removal of $0$ should yield a group under multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

A field has no non-zero divisors of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Note from the multiplication table, the one for the $\cdot$ operation, that

$2 \cdot 2 = 0; \tag 1$

thus $2$ is nilpotent; but a field $F$ can have no non-zero nilpotents (note $2 \ne 0$ since $3 + 2 = 1 \ne 3$).

If $F$ is a field and $a \in F$ *were* nilpotent, that is, if

$a^k = 0, \; 2 \le k \in \Bbb N, \tag 2$

then

$a = a^{1 - k} a^k = a^{1 - k} = 0; \tag 3$

which shows a field has no non-zero nilpotent elements.

Comment: Did you mean $a = a^{1-k} a^k = a^{1-k} \times 0 =0$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  yuppers, sure did!